# We have develop asp.net mvc 3 web app in vs 2010 with SQL server 2008

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, suse

I have developed asp.net mvc 3 app in vs 2010 with SQL server 2008 as database server.
Now I want to deploy the same web app over netowork with linux suse servers please help

Answer (score 0):

your project in .net and Microsoft technology and you must run it on IIS.
please select windows server.